# How can I use rhythm box and conky together?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, conky

I'm still fairly new at this and 12.04 LTS is my first hands on experience with Ubuntu all together. After spending a few weeks and trying to learn the in's and out's of the OS, I'm actually finding it easier to use in my off-time than Windows. However, my question today deals with the following:

I need help in trying to pull information from Rhythm Box in order to display it using Conky.

What I want is the following:

» Album Title

» Song Name

» Artist

» Album Picture

Is there a way to pull these and display them so that they will change as the songs change? I tried my hardest but I'm still a noob when it comes to using terminal and coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and run `man rhythmbox-client`. You can get all that information, except for the album art, which is a bit more difficult to deal with, being binary data rather than simple text.

Comment: Thanks,I see now, how much more difficult is the album art to deal with? Does it require a different method of coding?

Comment: You could possibly write a plug-in for rhythmbox, if one doesn't already exist, to integrate with conky. Album art can come from any number of sources, and isn't always a file on disk. You could of course, in your plug-in, always write a file to disk with the album art, though, and simply point conky at that file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the guiding advice! I appreciate you taking time out and helping me.

Comment: This causes my conky to freeze as soon as I start Rhythmbox. Any ideas?